# trouble importing components in react

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Hi I'm having trouble importing components from one jsx into another. I'm using a `django framework` to serve my webfiles and I've downloaded all the necessary tools (npm, webpack, webpack-bundle-tracker, babel loader, django-webpack loader). `Webpack` does a good job taking all of the seperate javascript files and turning them into a bundle in which my local django server can then render. The issue lies in when I try to `import a component from one jsx into another jsx`. There aren't any errors that I see but the javascript that I'm trying to import doesn't load on django.

Example: `File:index.js`

```
var React = require('react')
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom')
var Body = require('./app.js')

ReactDOM.render(<Body message="Welcome to my website"/>, document.getElementById('app1'))
```

Import file (which is in the same directory as index.js): `File:app.js`

```
var React = require('react')
var Body = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            bodymessage: this.props.message
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <h1>
            {this.state.bodymessage}
            </h1>
        )
    }
})
module.exports = Body;
```

Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Here's my webpack.config.js file :

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: './assets/js/index', 

    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'), 
        filename: '[name]-[hash].js', 
    },

    plugins: [
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'}), 
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery' 
        })
    ],

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.jsx?$/, 
                exclude: /node_modules/, 
                loader: 'babel-loader', 
                query: {
                    presets: ['react'] 
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'] 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Does this work when using webpack-dev-server?

Comment: No but I'll download that and try rendering the js using that server.

Comment: Still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `loader: 'babel-loader',` with `loader: 'babel',` in your webpack config